# Are there public onsen in Ogoto Onsen?

Tags: japan, hot-springs, kansai

I’m considering a day trip to Mt. Hiei. When descending on the Lake Biwa side, I notice that there is a station called Ogoto Onsen just north of the cable car. An evening in an onsen would be a great way to end the day before taking the train back home.

However, a quick search only returned ryokans with onsen baths attached; often these are not open to guests not staying at the ryokan. Are there any public onsens that accept day trip customers that I could visit?

Ideally, I would prefer late opening hours (9 pm or later) and open-air baths, if there happens to be a choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, almost all resorts in Ogoto Onsen offer day trip (日帰り *higaeri*) plans, ranging from a simple dip to packages with meals.  Here's a list (in Japanese) of 9 onsen with day trip plans:

https://tabijikan.jp/ogoto-onsen-day-trip-spa-35276/

For example, here are the meal-included day trip plans at Yumotokan, and they also offer onsen entry only for ¥2000/person until 9:30 PM.

https://www.yumotokan.co.jp/plan/